# "Error converting data type double to float" on inserting to DECIMAL column in SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I've got a SQL Server table with a `DECIMAL(10,2)` column. This should fit numbers up to `99999999.99`.  But when I insert any number `>= 1000` into it via the following C# code, I get the exception

> Error converting data type double to float.

If the value being inserted is `< 1000`, it works fine. The C# value is a double by the way.

Can anyone explain this please?

```
// ...

Database.AddInParameter(cmd, "@AssessmentScaleScore", DbType.Double,
                        (goal.StudentAssessmentInstanceID > 0
                         && goal.AssessmentScaleScore > 0)
                             ? goal.AssessmentScaleScore
                             : System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDouble.Null);

// ...

Database.ExecuteDataSet(cmd);
```

So again, the `goal.AssessmentScaleScore` is a `double`, and I'm inserting it into a `DECIMAL(10,2)` column in the DB.  If the value is `< 1000` it works fine, but if its `>= 1000` I get an exception.

I don't get it.

Comment: Out of interest, what culture are you running your code in? I wonder whether *something* is inappropriately converting the value to a string, and getting confused with thousands separators...

Comment: Turns out I just made a dumb mistake and was overflowing the parameter in my procedure, not the column in the DB.  I was banging my head trying to figure out why I couldn't save 1000.0 into a DECIMAL(10,2) column, but the parameter was mistakenly defined as DECIMAL(5,2) in the procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I jumped the gun asking this here.

Turns out I'm an idiot and my parameter in my stored procedure has it as DECIMAL(5,2) instead of DECIMAL(10,2) like the DB column.

So I was overflowing the parameter in the procedure, not the column in the DB.

Comment: You'd be suprised how common a mistake this is. If I had the rep I'd actually vote to reopen this.