# ColdFusion Error converting data type decimal to decimal

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I've got a bug in a CFStoredProc that's causing a crash whenever I try to send a decimal value to the stored procedure. The procedure simply inserts the value into a decimal(4,2) column in a SQL table. If I hard code a decimal value as the value of the cfprocparam, the procedure works. However, if the value is read in from a file, the I always get the error "Error converting data type decimal to decimal", no matter what I do to ensure the number is formatted correctly. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

My code essentially does the following:

1. Read a CSV file and convert it to a Query
2. Loop through the query to read the CSV data into variables
3. Send those variables to a stored procedure as cfprocparams

I have tried:

1. Formatting the number using numberFormat() before sending it to the stored procedure
2. Formatting the number using decimalFormat() before sending it to the stored procedure
3. Formatting the number using a custom function that does the same thing elsewhere in our application
4. Formatting the number using the aforementioned functions in the 'value' part of the cfprocparam

Code samples of what I've tried:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, 'select_rHeight')>
     <cfset headerName = form['select_rHeight']>
     <cfset rHeight = csvQuery[headerName]>
     <cfset rHeight = numberFormat(rHeight, "__.00")>
</cfif>

<cfstoredproc procedure="name" datasource="name">
     <cfprocparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DECIMAL" dbvarname="@Height" scale="2" value=#rHeight# null="#NOT len(trim(rHeight))#" />
</cfstoredproc>
```

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, 'select_rHeight')>
     <cfset headerName = form['select_rHeight']>
     <cfset rHeight = csvQuery[headerName]>
</cfif>

<cfstoredproc procedure="name" datasource="name">
     <cfprocparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DECIMAL" dbvarname="@Height" scale="2" value=#decimalFormat(rHeight)# null="#NOT len(trim(rHeight))#" />
</cfstoredproc>
```

I've done cfdumps and outputs of the variable before it gets sent to the stored procedure, and it always appears to be formatted correctly, but I always get this error message:
`[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Error converting data type decimal to decimal.`

Comment: what happens if you use `CF_SQL_DOUBLE` instead of `CF_SQL_DECIMAL`, together with `numberFormat(rHeight, "0.00")`?

Comment: I just tried that and it gave me the error "Error converting data type float to decimal."

Comment: I'm confused - does ColdFusion give you this error, or the database?

Comment: I guess it's the database, this is the full error message: java.sql.SQLException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Error converting data type float to decimal.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16737978/18771) suggests it might be a mismatch between your stored procedure parameter data type and your table data type.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can confirm that the data types in the procedure match the data types of the table columns : - (. It also works when I hard code a decimal value as the value of the cfprocparam, which makes me think this can't be the issue.

Comment: OK... when you run the procedure differently (first thing I would try: an explicit `<cfquery>`/`<cfqueryparam>`), does the behavior change?

Comment: Next next I would test would be boundaries. Can I insert `NULL`? Can I insert `0`? Can I insert other small integers? Can I insert the largest integer the data type supports? If that all checks out, can I manually provoke the error by inserting certain values? The *"error converting data type decimal to decimal"* occurs when a boundary is not met, e.g. when there are too many decimal places.

Comment: Thanks for the help - there weren't too many decimal places, but the value to the left of the decimal was too large. I made the rookie mistake of thinking decimal(5,2) meant 5 digits left of the decimal and 2 to the right.

Comment: Hey, it's always better when it turns out to be something stupid. :) A real bug causes a lot more difficulty.

Comment: Also: And that's why you should include the data/values you're testing with in the question.

Comment: @HDuck Could you convert that comment to an answer? You should be able to mark it as accepted as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the value being passed to the stored procedure was too large for the data type of the column into which it was being inserted. Data type was Decimal(3,2) and the value I was passing had more then three digits.

The solution was to check the size of the number being passed to the stored procedure, and give the user an error if the value is too large.

Thanks to @Tomalak for the help!